# Nautilus does not start properly: creates PID but no window: starts as root

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

Can anyone help me fix this, please?

Starting nautilus creates no window.  From a terminal, I get:

```
> nautilus
** Message: Init Stock Icons
Initializing nautilus-ideviceinfo extension
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
nautilus-wipe-Message: Initializing
```

... and nothing else.  Using ps I see:

```
ps -ef| grep nautilus
homer    13567     1  1 12:07 ?        00:00:00 nautilus /home/homer
homer    13648 13581  0 12:07 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nautilus
```

Using Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z has no effect:

```
^C^C^C^Z^Z^Z    <-(nothing happens)
```

I have to kill it from another terminal or System Monitor.

Starting as root I get:

```
> nautilus
** Message: Init Stock Icons
Initializing nautilus-ideviceinfo extension
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
nautilus-wipe-Message: Initializing

** (nautilus:13802): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed

** (nautilus:13802): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
```

... and nautilus starts.

Ctrl-Z also now works.

```
^C^C^C^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 nautilus
root@blackbox ~
> fg
nautilus
```

... nautilus still keeps running, even when I exit nautilus using Alt-F4. I have to use a second terminal to kill it.

**What I've tried according to other posts**

1. Reinstalling nautilus
2. Looking at permissions for the binary.

Comment: Starts fine after a reboot, but not a log-out/log-in.  
  
This problem **happens about once every month or two**.

Comment: This is not a question. If you want to report a bug, you can do that on Launchpad.net.